# Do materials approach black body behavior as temperature increases

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation

I have emittance curves of a material (that cannot be shared) that show an increase in emittance values over a wide wavelength range. As the temperature increases, the value for emittance increases, and the region in which the emittance is close to 1 increases spectrally.

So, my question is: Do materials approach blackbody emittance ($\epsilon = 1$) for all wavelengths as the temperature increases?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the material and its atomic structure. Look at the black body fit [for the sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Composition_and_power), which is a complex body. A very high temperature and not a perfect fit.

[The cosmic microwave backround](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#Features) radiation has the best experimentally fitted black body curve, and the energy is very low.

Also [this publication](https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-21-25-30964&id=275911) is interesting, *showing a large range of temperatures for fitting with a black body spectrum ;Perfect blackbody radiation from a graphene nanostructure with application to high-temperature spectral emissivity measurements*  .

Seems to me it will depend on the material under study.